# GAE dev_appserver crashes CGI / FastCGI on windows

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I installed python 2.7 and the Goole Cloud SDK.
After that I installed the php runtime using this command :

```
gcloud components install app-engine-php-windows
```

I then boot up a local dev server using this line :

```
dev_appserver.py <app-directory>
```

The server boots up fine, but when I send multiple requests to the server, I see multiple popups (one after te other) saying "CGI / FastCGI has stopped working".  I can then "Debug" or "Close program".

In the logfile I see this :

```
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
stdout:
ERROR:root:php failure (-1073741819) with:
stdout:
```

OS specifics : Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Also, adding extension="php_curl.dll" to php.ini does not avoid my problem as stated in other issues similar to this one.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: got the same issue, have you solved it already @xastor?

Comment: I believe I worked around this by using a different version of php (5.6.23 64-bit).

Comment: Thank you @xastor

Comment: Can you explain how you would do that @xastor? GAE has it's own supplied php, and I don't know how to make it use a different one